# Include native dlls in publish folder when targeting specific architecture

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec

My code is using some unmanaged dlls when running on win-x64. I'm trying to package those up as a separate nuget package. 
This is how I setup my nuget package:

```
.
│   MITKerberos.1.0.0.nuspec
└───runtimes
    └───win-x64
        └───native
                comerr64.dll
                gssapi64.dll
                k5sprt64.dll
                kdestroy.exe
                kinit.exe
                klist.exe
                kpasswd.exe
                krb5_64.dll
                krbcc64.dll
                leashw64.dll
                wshelp64.dll
                xpprof64.dll
```

My app is a netcoreapp which I've add the above package as a dependency and did a `dotnet publish -r win-x64`. The publish folder does not contain the expected dependencies. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Dumb error on my part - csproj was not saved in Visual Studio.